# Rename PDXObjectForm created in /Catalog

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

Using PDFbox, I want to add `PDXObjectForm` in the `/Catalog` entry. I have using this:

```
         PDStream formstream = new PDStream(template);
        PDXObjectForm form = new PDXObjectForm(formstream);
        PDResources res = new PDResources();
        form.setResources(res);
        appendRawCommands(formstream.createOutputStream(), "TESTING");
        // this creates AA. I need costum name Object
        PDDocumentCatalogAdditionalActions ac = new    PDDocumentCatalogAdditionalActions(res.getCOSDictionary());
        template.getDocumentCatalog().setActions(ac);
```

But the name of form in the /Catalog entry is now "AA". How can I change that name, for example, into "DSS"?

What is the best way to do this? I don't know how to add PDXObjectForm in the /Catalog entry. DocumentCatalogAdditionalActions is not the best solution, I know it's wrong and I want to use the proper method.

Can I use PDXObjectForm for the Document Secure Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
    PDDocumentCatalog cat = template.getDocumentCatalog();
    COSDictionary catDoc = cat.getCOSDictionary();

    COSDictionary dssDictionary = new COSDictionary();
    catDoc.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"), dssDictionary);
```

1. DSS must be `Dictionary`, not `PDXObjectForm`.
2. `PDDocumentCatalogAdditionalActions` was not necessary. It would create "AA" because of the `AdditionalActions` which was not that I needed.